# How to look under a surface from Q3dSurface?

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, surface

I have plotted a surface with the Q3dSurface class from Qt Data Visualization. Unfortunately, it seem impossible to rotate the 3d surface to look under it.

The class Q3dCamera from the Q3dScene seem to be responsible for the orbit position of the camera and its manipulation. But there is no way to define the range of the y-axis.

Any suggestion how to achieve this?